# Drupal Rules sending an email address to a user reference

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a custom node. One of the fields it has is a user reference. I wish to send an email to that user of that reference when the node is updated. I am trying to use the Rules module to do to this. I can get the uid but not the mail address from the tokens.

Is there any way I can execute some php from within the to field and the body. My php is being read as text.

I am using the send to arbitrary email address.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [user_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_load/6) function to load up the user's object, then specify the mail address based on that.

```
// Change $node->field_userreference to point to the correct CCK field    
$recipient = user_load($node->field_userreference);
return $recipient->mail;
```

Comment: @Will: you have to wrap it in <?php

Comment: This is the right approach, but I think you typically need to add the full array (ie, `$node->field_userrreference['0']['uid']`).